# Why does convergence to zero in two norms imply equivalence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed space with two norms $f$ and $g$.
Prove that these statements are equivalent:

$\{z_n\}$ tends to 0 as $n → ∞$ in $f\;\; $    $\forall \{z_n\}\in V$

Comment: write explicitly what means "$\|.\|_1,\|.\|_2$ are equivalent"

Comment: This is the same as saying the open-ball $\|x\|_1 < 1$ is contained  in some open ball $\|x\|_2 < c$, and conversely. Now what happens if $\|x_n\|_1 \to 0$ iff $\|x_n\|_2 \to 0$ ?

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions,

Answer (score 5):

Assume there is no $\alpha$ such that $\Vert x\Vert_1\le \alpha\Vert x\Vert_2$ for all $x$. So for every $n\in\Bbb N$ there is some $x_n$ such that $\Vert x_n\Vert_1>n\Vert x_n\Vert_2$. Let

$$z_n=\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n \Vert x_n\Vert_2}$$
so $\Vert z_n\Vert_2=\frac1{\sqrt n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ wheras $\Vert z_n\Vert_1\ge \sqrt n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}+\infty$.